# SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable in jax-rs maven project

Tags: java, rest, maven, jsp, jax-rs

After adding the following code:

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public WatchList find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    WatchList results = em.createNamedQuery("WatchList.findById", WatchList.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
    return results;
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public void findById(
        @Context final HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/AMLManagement.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("items", find("id"));
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

I got the error `Severe:   WebModule[/MavenProjectTest]StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.`

And this: `Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.`

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this? Did i do anything wrong in the above code that causes this error?

Comment: Is there more of a stack trace? Also what makes you think the code you posted has anything to do with it?

Comment: @peeskillet I got this error right after adding this code, I didn't have the problem before

Comment: don't you need a `@Path` for the `find` method?

Comment: @asgs I don't know, I've done the same thing on my findAll but then i have a "@override", but that didn't work on this one, I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had to add a path, and the id i was passing wasn't supposed to be a string, and I had to add a `@Pathparam` to the findId, I solved it like this:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public WatchList find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    WatchList results = em.createNamedQuery("WatchList.findById", WatchList.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
    return results;
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public void findId(@PathParam("id") Integer id,
        @Context final HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/AMLManagement.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("items", find(id));
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```